# building html table with jquery that contains links (<a href...)

Tags: html, jquery

I am building a html table based on results I get from an ajax call.
I can build the table fine, but I am also trying to put links in the  that the user can click on; however, all I am getting is the "text" of the .  What am I doing wrong??

here is my ajax code that builds the table

```
    $.ajax({
                url: '../Members/GetStatements',
                data: 'Year=' + yr,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    
                    $('#stmtTBL').find('tbody').detach();
                    $('#stmtTBL').append($('<tbody>'));

                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        var linktxt = "";
                        if (item.DBStored == 1){
                            //linktxt = '<a href="' + '../members/_ShowStatement?MonthlyStatementID=' + item.MonthlyStatementID + '" target=' + '"_blank"' + '>' + item.StatementName + '</a>'
                            linktxt = '<a href="#" target=' + '"_blank"' + '>' + item.StatementName + '</a>';
                            linktxt = '<a href="#">test</a>';

                        } else {
                            linktxt = '<a href="' + 'https://www.somelink.com/statements/' + item.FileName + '" target=' + '"_blank"' + '>' + item.StatementName + '</a>';
                        }

                        var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                            $('<td>').text(linktxt)
                        ).appendTo('#stmtTBL > tbody');
                    });
```

I imagine I need to use something like ".append" with an attribute but I dont know the syntax for it,  and I am having problems searching for what I want.

Comment: Change `$('<td>').text(linktxt)` to `$('<td>').html(linktxt)`

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the answer from this post:

[Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

```
    $("#tableID").find('tbody')
.append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>')
        .append($('<img>')
            .attr('src', 'img.png')
            .text('Image cell')
        )
    )
);
```

using the attr and append!!!  thanks guys